# Run all the tests that are in sub directories in a unique file using testthat

Tags: r, testing, rstudio, testthat

When we use testthat in R, the package looks in `tests/testthat` directory and execute all the files that starts with 'test'... but if i have this type of organization:

```
tests

--/testthat

----/case1

------/Test1.R

------/Test2.R

----/case2

------/Test3.R

----/..
```

- How can I execute all the tests in a unique command or file?
- I try to change the path of testthat tests to `'tests/testthat/**/*.R'` but `testthat` not iterate over directories.

Anybody knows a solution?

Comment: I would put test1 etc in the testthat folder (and give them better names than test1); use `context` to describe the context of the set of tests you are running. See for example the [tidytext tests](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/tree/master/tests/testthat). Use `test_that` with text to show what you are testing. You can have multiple `context` calls in one test file if you want to.

Comment: @phiver the names are simple examples, and i know that testthat execute all the tests that are in tests/testthat but i want to keep this hierarchy of directories and get the way to execute all this tests only in a one file. The idea is search a way to iterate over the directories and execute all the tests.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `test_dir`? A file in the main folder which calls on test_dir to call on case1 to run the tests in that folder.

Comment: I had try this but it says this error: "Error in UseMethod("xml_add_child") :" and i cannot execute the tests in 'case1' folder.

Comment: I have no issues using test_dir. The error looks to be coming from xml2. This is a suggests from testthat. Check if you have this package installed on your machine.